# Symfony 4.1 - manually wire single service requires _defaults: public: true

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have the following services.yaml file:    # This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
    # Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    App\Service\Processor\TestClauses:
        public: true


    App\Service\Processor\Factory:
        arguments:
          - 'App\Service\Processor\TestClauses'
          -
            - 'MilkProductionProcessor'
```

ie. I'm happy to autowire everything, but this one service that needs an array as input.

This does not seem to work unless I make all services public. My understanding of the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services is that I just have to make services public that I want to inject manually

The "root service" is injected to a command. When I run this command:

1) With the services.yaml as is I get

```
[WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:                               

In Factory.php line 15:

  Argument 1 passed to App\Service\Processor\Factory::__construct() must impl  
  ement interface App\Service\Processor\TestClausesInterface, string given, c  
  alled in /home/jochen/projects/freshagenda/symfony/var/cache/dev/Container7  
  4x3zkp/getProcessFilesCommandService.php on line 16                          




  There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.  

  Did you mean this?                                     
      doctrine:mapping
```

2) When I make services:_defaults:public true

it moves forward

Comment: No need to make anything public at all.  You just need an @ to inject a service:  '@App\Service\Processor\TestClauses'  What you have is trying to inject a string.

Comment: is single quote required or does double quote work as well

Comment: Not sure.  That is a yaml thing.  Don't see any reason not to use single quotes.

Comment: Only single quotes are future proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
App\ServiceThatNeedsArrayAsInput:
    arguments:
       $array: ...
```

Everything else can be autowired and autoconfigured. In constructor of the `ServiceThatNeedsArrayAsInput` you should receive that `$array` from arguments - difference from earlier versions is that you explicitly say to which variable you wish to bind argument defined in `services.yml`

```
// ServiceThatNeedsArrayAsInput.php 
public function __construct(array $array) {} // Only array from arguments
public function __construct(array $array, AutowiredService $service) {} // Just add it here and DI will autoinject it, no need to change services.yml
```

## Your example

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do here but if you want to inject autowired services, there's no need to define it explicitly in services.yml - check the above example - you only need to add Classname to constructor.

```
App\Service\Processor\Factory:
    arguments:
      $array: ['MilkProductionProcessor']
```